# Move down 5 cells on column A, after pasting from the clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard, paste

I am using macro to  paste Unicode Text which works perfectly. What i want in the macro to do is after pasting the contents from the clipboard, the cell selector should move down 5 empty cells for the next paste when i want to paste.

This is my macro code

```
Sub PASTE()
'
' PASTE Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it, you need to move the selection to 5 empty cells down of the current selected cell (in which you just pasted a Unicode text).

I wrote the sub "MoveDown5" and called it on your sub. The final result is:

```
Sub PASTE()
' PASTE Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False
MoveDown5
End Sub

Sub MoveDown5()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0
Do While counter < 5
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

The code moves down one cell and test if it is empty. If yes, it counts as an empty cell. If not, just go ahead to the next loop.

Then repeat the loop one cell down until the counter is 5 (no more <5).